# IOS iphone app development - how do you hide files within resources directory?

Tags: ios

IOS iphone app development - how do you  hide files within resources directory?

If someone wanted to pull the assets from a resource file say copyrighted images or mp3's would they not just need to right click app icon to show package contents.From there they can just open png's and mp3's from the bundle - which doesn't offer much digital rights protection.

I am hoping there is a toggle so that these items can be hidden.

Many thanks

Magnus

Comment: There’s no "magic toggle". You may want to embed your files in as blobs in a SQLite database, but that only provides obfuscation, not encryption. They'll only be harder to find.

Comment: Anyway, there's no way to forbid the option to take a screenshot of your running app, at least none that I'm aware of. Why not watermark your copyrighted material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a way to hide files, but an option would be to encrypt them.

You can encode file data in base64 strings, which can be encrypted by an algorithm of your choice. 
When you wish to get a resource get the corresponding text file, decrypt it and recreate it (the approach is similar to serializing, but with an additional encryption step).
This way, in your app bundle you will only be storing text files containing meaningless string characters.

Not sure how safe this way is, but it's an option.

Hope this helps, Vlad.